# VSTS Release Definition - how to schedule monthly?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, release, release-management

Defining a VSTS Release Definition via:

- Edit Release Definition
- Pipeline
- Environments
- Pre Deployment Release Conditions
- Triggers
- After Release
- Schedule

A user has the options to ENABLE and SCHEDULE a release to an ENVIRONMENT at a day/time of their choosing.

Is it possible to schedule a release once per month ?

Context: Artifacts are .git master branch exported to an Escrow import workflow.

Testing the schedule options the UI currently offers a user the option to select:

- Day of the week
- Time of Day
- Time Zone

Maybe a community module exists that can be imported into VSTS to offer more options or VSTS has an option hidden away somewhere else ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trigger release monthly is not available for now. As you saw, there only as working days, time and time zone for schedule.

But there has an user voice [Scheduled builds - More flexible timing configuration](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17932441-scheduled-builds-more-flexible-timing-configurat) which suggest more flexible time configuration including (monthly configuration). You can vote and follow up for this user voice.

Comment: Thank you Marina. Great help. Scott.

Comment: Is no longer available ooohhh

Answer (score 3):

I’ve found a really simple way to achieve one-off or scheduled releases.

Just use the VSTS CLI tool, in the marketplace...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.cli

It’s published by MS and it’s super easy to kick off builds and releases from the command line.

Just use task scheduler. Works an absolute treat for me.

Specifically, this is the command you need to execute:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cli/vsts/release?view=vsts-cli-latest#vsts-release-create

Comment: Thanks Simon for posting. Will have a look.

Comment: @scott_lotus No problem, good luck. It works really well for me. Got all sorts of scheduled jobs using it.